# How to filter Pandas Dataframe rows which contains any string from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, filter

I have dataframe that has values like those:

```
  A                    B
["I need avocado"   "something"]
["something"      "I eat margarina"]
```

And I want to find rows that:

In **any** column of the row, the column's value is contained in a list. 
for example, for the list:

```
["apple","avocado","bannana"]
```

And only this line should match:
    ["I need avocado"   "something"]

This line doesnt work:

```
dataFiltered[dataFiltered[col].str.contains(*includeKeywords)]
```

Returns:

```
{TypeError}unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try .str.contains('|'.join(includeKeywords)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=['I need avocado', 'something', 'useless', 'nothing'],
    B=['something', 'I eat margarina', 'eat apple', 'more nothing']
))
includeKeywords = ["apple", "avocado", "bannana"]
```

---

#### Problem

```
                A                B
0  I need avocado        something  # True 'avocado' in A
1       something  I eat margarina
2         useless        eat apple  # True 'apple' in B
3         nothing     more nothing
```

---

#### Solution

- [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to make `df` a `Series` and enable us to use the `pandas.Series.str` accessor functions
- [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `'|'.join(includeKeywords)`
- [`pandas.Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) with argument `level=0` because we added a level to the index when we stacked

---

```
df[df.stack().str.contains('|'.join(includeKeywords)).any(level=0)]

                A          B
0  I need avocado  something
2         useless  eat apple
```

---

#### Details

This produces a `regex` search string.  In `regex`, `'|'` means **`or`**.  So for a `regex` search, this says match `'apple'`, `'avocado'`, or `'bannana'`

```
kwstr = '|'.join(includeKeywords)
print(kwstr)

apple|avocado|bannana
```

Stacking will flatten our `DataFrame`

```
df.stack()

0  A     I need avocado
   B          something
1  A          something
   B    I eat margarina
2  A            useless
   B          eat apple
3  A            nothing
   B       more nothing
dtype: object
```

Fortunately, the `pandas.Series.str.contains` method can handle `regex` and it will produce a boolean `Series`

```
df.stack().str.contains(kwstr)

0  A     True
   B    False
1  A    False
   B    False
2  A    False
   B     True
3  A    False
   B    False
dtype: bool
```

At which point we can cleverly use `pandas.Series.any` by suggesting it only care about `level=0`

```
mask = df.stack().str.contains(kwstr).any(level=0)
mask

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

By using `level=0` we preserved the original index in the resulting `Series`. This makes it perfect for filtering `df`

```
df[mask]

                A          B
0  I need avocado  something
2         useless  eat apple
```

Comment: Wow! short and perfect

Comment: when only looking at a single column, a one liner using regex alone is enough: `df[df.colname.str.contains('|'.join(includeKeywords))]`. Very simple, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Take advantage of the `any()` function and use a list comprenesion in an `df.apply()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["I need avocado","I eat margarina"])
print(df)
#                  0
# 0   I need avocado
# 1  I eat margarina

includeKeywords = ["apple","avocado","bannana"]

print(df[df.apply(lambda r: any([kw in r[0] for kw in includeKeywords]), axis=1)])
#                 0
# 0  I need avocado
```

To make this a bit clearer, you basically need to make a mask that returns True/False for each row

```
mask = [any([kw in r for kw in includeKeywords]) for r in df[0]]
print(mask)
```

Then you can use that mask to print the selected rows in your DataFrame

```
# [True, False]
print(df[mask])
#                 0
# 0  I need avocado
```

I am showing you both ways because while the `df.apply()` method is handy for a one liner, it is really slow compared to a standard list comprehension. So if you have a small enough set, feel free to use `df.apply()`. Otherwise, I'd suggest the python comprehension over the pandas method.

Comment: Thank you. Your first solution didnt work for me. The second one only works for one column. I want to get all rows that contains the values of the list in any column

Comment: I can "join" masks to one mask, but is there a way with pandas?

Comment: Well, there are several ways you could do it. You could put another comprehension layer, or make a series of masks in a list of lists than zip that up and do `[any(i1, i2, i3,...) for i1, i2, i3 in zip(m1, m2, m3)]`