# Filtering a pandas dataframe based presence of substrings in column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Not sure if this is a 'filtering with pandas' question or one of text analysis, however:

Given a df,

```
d = {
    "item": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    "report": [
        "john rode the subway through new york",
        "sally says she no longer wanted any fish, but",
        "was not submitted",
        "the doctor proceeded to call washington and new york",
    ],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Resulting in

```
item, report
a, "john rode the subway through new york"
b, "sally says she no longer wanted any fish, but"
c, "was not submitted"
d, "the doctor proceeded to call washington and new york"
```

And a list of terms to match:

```
terms = ["new york", "fish"]
```

How would you reduce the the df to have the following rows, based on whether a substring in `terms` is found in column `report` and so that `item` is preserved?

```
item, report
a, "john rode the subway through new york"
b, "sally says she no longer wanted any fish, but"
d, "the doctor proceeded to call washington and new york"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, which is based on `numpy`:

```
strings = np.array(df['report'], dtype=str)
substrings = np.array(terms)

index = np.char.find(strings[:, None], substrings)
mask = (index >= 0).any(axis=1)

df.loc[mask]
```

Output:

```
  item                                             report
0    a              john rode the subway through new york
1    b      sally says she no longer wanted any fish, but
3    d  the doctor proceeded to call washington and ne...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Using a word boundary with your regex will ensure that "fish" will get matched, but "fishy" will not (as an example)

```
m = df['report'].str.contains(r'\b{}\b'.format(r'\b|\b'.join(terms)))

df2 = df.loc[m]
```

Output:

```
  item                                             report
0    a              john rode the subway through new york
1    b      sally says she no longer wanted any fish, but
3    d  the doctor proceeded to call washington and ne...
```

Answer (score 1):

Pulling from another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941100/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-rows-which-contains-any-string-from-a-list):

You can change your `terms` into a regex-usable single string (that is, `|` delimited) and then use `df.Series.str.contains`.

```py
term_str = '|'.join(terms) # makes a string of 'new york|fish'
df[df['report'].str.contains(term_str)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
df[df['report'].apply(lambda x: any(term in x for term in terms))]
```

Output:

```
  item                                             report
0    a              john rode the subway through new york
1    b      sally says she no longer wanted any fish, but
3    d  the doctor proceeded to call washington and ne...
```